# Pi Day question

Tags: pi

Everyone today is talking about Pi Day and the match to 3/14/15 at 9:26:53 AM. As I've become old, my brain doesn't work so well, so I could be way off on this, but if we include decimal fractions of a second here, couldn't we take this match out even farther than the 53? I was thinking that at some point, the time could exactly match the digits in pi for as many places as we'd like to go.
For example at some point the calendar and clock would show 3/14/15 9:26:53.58979 and this could go on to any digit in pi as far as we wished to go, even billions of places.

Is this correct or have I lost all my math ability?

Comment: If time is not discrete, you seem right.

Comment: This is all wrong any way, as it's not 3/14/15: it makes not sense (in this mathematical context) to list month/day/year/hour. You have to be consistent and order the sub-units. Then we get 2015/03/15/09.26.53 etc.

Comment: They both give as much sense. Units does not make any sense in mathematics. Mathematics make sense from the moment you define a convention (so here American formatted date is the convention used). Your convention does not make more sense than any other (as it is anyway, just a convention..)

Comment: I hope your question burns in hell.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but we do not have the technology yet. On that day, at an instantaneous moment in time, the exact value of pi would be passed. However, atomic clocks today are only accurate up to $10^{-21}$ of a second, which makes it only available to express 31 digits right now.